# Changing kernel in a system not booting

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, kernel, system-installation

I have a dell inspiron laptop and have just installed 12.04.

The system hangs on boot after 'Switching to clocksource TSC'.

I've searched all the questions here and had no luck changing bios settings or boot parameters.

I'd like to try a different kernel but since I'm currently running from a USB stick the normal install procedures won't work.

How do I install another kernel to my hard drive when I can't boot into it?

Also which kernel would you recommend I try? I'm currently trying 3.11.0-15-generic.

Also how do I check what kernel is currently running? If it boots ok from the USB stick maybe I should use that kernel?

Thanks for reading, hope someone can help.